# Python script to remove multiple blank lines between paragraphs and end of file

Tags: python, file

I wrote a python script to capture the data I want but
I have a resulting text file that contains multiple paragraphs but each paragraph is separated by varying blank lines - anywhere from 2 to 8.

My file also has multiple blank lines at the end of the file.

I would like Python to leave no more than 2 blank lines between paragraphs and and no blank lines at the end of the text file.

I have experimented with a loop and line.strip, replace etc but I clearly have little idea how to put this together.

examples of what I have been using so far

```
wf = open(FILE,"w+")
for line in wf:
         newline = line.strip('^\r\n')
         wf.write(newline)
         wf.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easier to remove all blank lines and then insert two blank lines between paragraphs (and none at the end) than counting all blank lines and only removing if there's more than two. Unless you're dealing with huge files I don't think there's going to be any performance difference between the two approaches. Here's a quick and dirty solution using `re`:

```
import re
# Reads from file
f = open('test.txt', 'r+')
txt = f.read()
# Removes all blank lines
txt = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', txt)
# Adds two blanks between all paragraphs
txt = re.sub(r'\n', '\n\n\n', txt)
# Removes the blank lines from the EOF
txt = re.sub(r'\n*\Z', '', txt)
# Writes to file and closes
f.write(txt)
f.close()
```

Before:

```
One line below

None below
Three below



EOF with one blank line below (stackoverflow's code thingy omits it)
```

After:

```
One line below


None below


Three below


EOF with one blank line below
```

Comment: Many thanks for your replies, I will try the Python method as the rest of my script is written in Python.  I will update once have run.

Comment: When I tried Alex script I noticed it did not alter the blank lines between paragraphs. When I produce the file it is emailed out normally. the received file in outlook has  strange charaters there 
(about 4 small square boxes at the start of sentence) Looking further on notepad plus, what I thought were blank lines seem to have CR LF , LF, CR LF, LF ,LF CR LF in sort of that order - either one LF or a CR LF  on each new line. Not sure why its doing this but could I ask how I could modify the script to remove these first and then continue with Alexs script above?  Thankyou.

Comment: Try '\r\n' instead of '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some untested code:

```
import re

new_lines = re.compile('\n{2,9}')

with open(FILE) as f:
    contents = f.read()
contents = re.sub(new_lines, '\n\n\n', contents.strip())
with open(FILE, 'w') as f:
    f.write(contents)
```

First the blank lines at the end are removed. Then the regular expression matches instances of 2 to 9 newlines in the contents of the file, and replaces these with 3 newlines by the `re.sub()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer requested is python, but I believe that might be an overkill.

Why not preprocess the file directly on your shell ? Use `grep` or `sed` or `awk` to accomplish this.

Here is the grep version:

```
$ grep -v '^$' input.txt > output.txt
```

Here is a [quick reference I found](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-command-remove-all-blank-lines/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the part of the question that says "leave no more than 2 blank lines between paragraphs and and no blank lines at the end of the text file" -- technically "0" is "no more than 2" but I think the intention is to *leave* up to two blank lines between non-blank ones.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the question has not really been answered.
Here is a solution that works, but I think it could be better.

```
newtext = ''    
counter = 0
for line in text.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if len(line)==0:
        counter += 1
        if counter<=2:
            newtext += line + '\n'
    else:
        newtext += line + '\n'
        counter = 0
```

Comment: The maximum number of blank lines can be changed. Two blank lines are allowed here.